# How can I pass the variables from int function 1 to another int function and add every time?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

I want to program a game where the user has 10 days. I have an int main and a LOT of int functions. The user can visit a lot of functions everytime easily and the functions represent the locations in the game. What I want to do is for the day to increase by 1 everytime I leave a location. lets say that my first location is function1, in here it will state that it is day 1, once i leave the location, it will bring me to another function and it will state day 2.

I havent tried to actually code it as I am a bit lost on how the other functions will know the values of the other. I think that the code I want will need to make use of pointers and paramenters but I'm not very sure on how to get that work. This is what I have for now.

```
int function1()
{
    
    int day = 1;
  
    
    printf ("today is day %d", day);
   
}
```

Comment: You declare that `function1` will ***retrurn*** and `int` value, but it never does. Perhaps that could be used to pass the new value back to the calling `main` function? And pass the current value as an argument to the functions you call? So e.g. `int day = 0; day = function1(day);` etc.?

Comment: `void inc(int *a) { (*a)++; }` increments the variable whose pointer you pass to it ( call it with `inc(&myInt);` ) it myInt should be increased

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword is one way to do it.

```
int function1()
{
    static int day = 0;  
    //this will only happen once, no matter how many times you call the function

    if(day <= 10)
    {
        day++;
    }

    printf ("today is day %d", day);

    return day;
}
```

But since you're probably going to need that variable elsewhere in your program, it's likely best to make it global like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int day;  //it's global since it's declared outside of main.

int function1()
{
    if(day <= 10)
    {
        day++;
    }

    printf ("today is day %d", day);

    return day;
}
int main()
{
   //your code goes here.
}
```

Be careful with this, since if you say `int day` in `main` thinking it refers to your gloabl variable `day`, you will be sorely mistaken.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int day; // global variable

int main()
{
    int day = 0;  
//this is a local variable that has nothing to do with the global variable "day".
}
```

Comment: Contrary to what you wrote using a global variable is generally *not* a good way, and using a static local is only marginally better. Instead, the usually best way is to use parameters and return values to pass data into and out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum (int a);
int main(){
 int day = 1;
 sum(day);
}
int sum (int a){
 a += 1;
 printf("\n value of 'a' in the called function is = %d", a);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is nice to have all of your game's *state* collected into one global structure, that you initialize at startup, for example

```
struct GameState {
    int day;
    int health;
    int shield;
    int points;
} gs;

int main()
{
    gs.day = 1;
    gs.health = 100;
    gs.health = 0;
    gs.points = 0;
}
```

And all your functions can call a day incrementer when they're done:

```
int function1()
{
    while (doing_stuff)
    {
        // do stuff
        if (unexpected())
            return next_day();
    }

    return next_day();
}
```

And the helper function to increment the day count

```
int next_day()
{
    return gs.day++;
}
```